# Could not fetch data from Database using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue.I  need to fetch data from a Database using PHP and MySQL but its displaying the following message:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0021 sec )
```

I have 1 set of data like the below table.

**kf_admin**:

```
id   username   password    status

1    admin      8bb7101921   1
```

The password part is an encrypted password and its datatype is varchar. When I execute the following query it results in the above message.

```
select * from kf_admin where username='admin' and password='8bb7101921' ;
```

But when I remove the password part from the query, it show the row data. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: That should work, so I have to assume that the password is not what is being shown or you keyed it in wrong. Alternatively there is an unprintable character in the password, or a space. How did your Encrypt the password, or do you mean Hash

Comment: Are you keying that query directly into something like phpMyAdmin or are you doing this from PHP but just now showing us the PHP code you are using

Comment: one of the possibility you couldn't get the answer due to eighter the username field or password field having values with trailing spaces,
 ie; password with a extra space . like this '8bb7101921    '..
please check this scenario...

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from kf_admin where trim(username)='admin' and trim(password)='8bb7101921' ;
```

Try this, may be leading or trailing space in the field

Comment: Then you need to take **a lot more care** when creating these passwords or when storing them to your database